# keyframe not working on Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have this very simple code to simulate a marquee.it's working on all browser except Chrome.
I have tried the -webkit- but still no luck, and what drives me crazy is when I try it here http://jsfiddle.net/XxUXD/2566/ it works like a charm on Chrome.
So could you please tell me what did I do wrong?

HTML

```
<div class="marquee">  the brown fox jumped over the lazy dog </div>
```

CSS

```
   /* Make it a marquee */
.marquee {

    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: marquee 50s linear infinite;
}

.marquee:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused
}

/* Make it move */
@keyframes marquee {
    0%   { text-indent: 27.5em }
    100% { text-indent: -105em }
}
```

Comment: Sorry about my previous comment, next time I'll read the entire question. What is on your actual site that is not in your jsfiddle? It's hard to answer a question when you say it works somewhere we can verify but won't work somewhere we can't see.

Comment: there is no difference between the code I use on my site and on jsfiddle. you can copy the code I pasted on any empty html file and you will see what I mean.

Comment: 40.0.2214.91 m. Updates are controlled here at work or else I'd jump to your version for absolute confirmation. But your jsfiddle works just like you say it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's necessary to use -webkit- in this instance.

That means for`-webkit-animation`, `@-webkit-keyframes`, and `webkit-animation-play-state`.

See the following JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nd3oebsb/

Comment: If I answered your question, please indicate so by giving me a check mark on my post. Thanks.